# How to run db.currentOp() using the MongoDB native Node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can't seem to find a way of retrieving information on the database current operation using the *mongodb* module in Node.js.

I have tried something this:

```
mongodb   = require 'mongodb'
server    = new mongodb.Server 'localhost', 27017
connector = new mongodb.Db 'test', server

connector.open (err, db) ->
    if not err?
        db.admin().command {currentOp: 1}, (err, doc) ->
            if not err?
                console.log doc
```

of course without any result.

Does anybody have a pointer?

Answer (score 8):

The way to do this directly from node mongodb native driver:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/', function (err, db) {

    if (err) { throw err; }

    db.collection('$cmd.sys.inprog').findOne(function (err, data) {

        if (err) { throw err; }
        console.log(data.inprog);

    });
});
```

Comment: How can I use db.killOp(opid) using the MongoDB native Node.js driver?

Comment: When I was using the code above, seems `MongoClient` prepend default collection name. Then it raised an error said `Invalid collection name: admin.$cmd.sys.inprog`. Does anyone met the same problem?

Comment: I finally found the problem. From the mail thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/2BpMd8mlEvI they said from MongoDB 3.2, client cannot touch system collection through `find`. Now if I use `db.command({ currentOp: 1 })` I can get results back.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a command on the shell, it is not a real command. Instead, you need to query the `$cmd.sys.inprog` collection with `findOne()`. On the MongoDB shell, you would do:

```
db.$cmd.sys.inprog.findOne();
```

Comment: Thank you for this info! It looks like this is a feature still to be implemented in the native MongoDB driver for Node.js...

Comment: I'll ask whether this is the way forward.

Comment: How can I use db.killOp(opid) using the MongoDB native Node.js driver?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the currentOp command on MongoDB 3.2 (see the shell definition of [db.currentOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) for details).

`db.eval("return db.currentOp()",function (err, data) {
  console.log('currentOp',err,data);
});`

Answer (score 0):

implementation using mongoose:

```
        let db = mongoose.connection.db;
        db.command({ currentOp: 1 }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(`Agenda :: Kill long mongo queries | Error: ${err}`);
            } else {
                for (let oper in result.inprog) {
                    let op = result.inprog[oper - 0];
                    if (op.secs_running > ENUMS.MONGO_KILL_AFTER_SECONDS && op.op === "query" && !op.ns.startsWith("local")) {
                        console.info(`Agenda :: Kill long mongo queries | Killing opId: ${op.opid} Running over ${op.secs_running}`);
                        db.killOp(op.opid);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Based on [gist](https://gist.github.com/comerford/9248866)

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work, disregarding the MongoDB native driver for Node.js.

```
exec = require('child_process').exec

exec '/usr/bin/mongo --quiet --host="localhost:27017" "test" --eval "printjson(db.currentOp())"', (err, stdout) ->
    console.error "#{err.message}" if err?

    console.log JSON.parse stdout
```

Shouldn't this feature be implemented in the driver?